# HTTP request pythonanywhere flask server using esp8266 AT commands

Tags: http, flask, at-command, arduino-esp8266

I have an esp8266 connected to wifi and I want it to send/get data from a Flask webserver hosted by eu.pythonanywhere.com.

I am using the Arduino IDE to communicate with the esp8266 via a USB to UART converter.

When using `AT+CIPSTART` to create a tcp connection, it connects correctly but when i try to send a get request : `GET / HTTP/1.1` or `GET /?data=2 HTTP/1.1`using `AT+CIPSEND` i get "SEND OK" but then no answer from the server. Adding "\r\n" to the end of the request gets me a 400 Bad Request error.
I also tried using `AT+HTTPCLIENT` but the esp8266 just gives me "ERROR"

Here is my python code for the server:

```py
from flask import Flask,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods = ['POST','GET','PUT'])
def hello_world():
    data = '0'
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        data='1'
        #data = request.json['data']
    elif request.method == 'GET' :
        data = request.args.get('data')
        #return "0" 
    return data
```

I have tried the PUT,POST, and GET methods but i didn't manage to get any of them working. I've also tried to send a GET request to other websites such as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) with no response.

However when i send something like "hello" or smth that is not a http request, i get a 400 Bad Request response from the server.

I should mention that I'm not really used to deal with http requests.

Thank you for your time.